Running an exe on a remote Azure VM from a .NET 8 C# function app
I'm tasked with writing a function app in C# that is going to be responsible for running an exe on a remote VM. I've been trying to use Azure.ResourceManager SDK to do it but can't seem to work out how to create a RunCommandInput.
Here is what my code looks like so far:
public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequestData req)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Invoking remote executable on Windows VM using RunCommand");

    // Azure authentication and setup
    string tenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_TENANT_ID");
    string clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_ID");
    string clientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET");
    string subscriptionId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID");
    string resourceGroupName = "YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP";
    string vmName = "YOUR_VM_NAME";

    // Use DefaultAzureCredential for authentication
    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

    // Initialize Azure resource manager client
    var armClient = new ArmClient(credential, subscriptionId);

    // Get the specific VM resource
    var subscription = armClient.GetSubscriptionResource(new ResourceIdentifier($"/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}"));
    ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup = subscription.GetResourceGroup(resourceGroupName);
    VirtualMachineResource vmResource = resourceGroup.GetVirtualMachine(vmName);

    try
    {
        // Use Azure Compute's RunCommand to execute a PowerShell script on the VM
        var runCommandInput = new RunCommandInput("RunPowerShellScript");
        //{
        //    Script = new List<string> { commandToExecute },
        //    Parameters = new List<RunCommandInputParameter> {}
        //};

        _logger.LogInformation("Running command on VM...");

        // Execute the command
        var runCommandResult = await vmResource.RunCommandAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, runCommandInput);

        // Log the result
        //_logger.LogInformation($"Command executed successfully. Status: {runCommandResult.Value.Status}");
    }
    catch (RequestFailedException ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Failed to execute command on VM: {ex.Message}");
    }

    return new OkObjectResult("OK");
}

Now RunCommandInput class has fields called parameters and scripts but these are both read-only and can't be assigned to directly, nor have I found any helper/extension methods that will set these fields.
There is a constructor that sets these fields but its an internal constructor, so I can't invoke it.
Here is a link to the source code of this class: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/compute/Azure.ResourceManager.Compute/src/Generated/Models/RunCommandInput.cs
Can someone please explain how am I supposed to use the RunCommandInput class as there is very little to no information available online.
Also, is my solution actually workable or is it something that can't be achieved by ARM SDK?

Instead of doing all of this, I'd look into seeing how you can trigger something on the VM that would run the exe. For example a lightweight HTTP service or an app that is waiting for a queue message.

I've thought about it and unfortunately due to constraints beyond my control, I not allowed to host any HTTP service or install any extra tools/frameworks on the VM.
